# Shared Server can't connect to SMTP account using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I have the following configuration for PHPMailer:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.alestraune.net.mx';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'prux@notrealdomain.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxxxx';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

When I try to connect to the server I get the following error:

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)

But when I test it through my localserver (wamp) I have no problems.

Currently I'm sending the email from hostgator. I have already tried using the SMTPSecure configurations (tls, ssl) with no success.

Thanks!

Comment: You also need to set `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` for that code to work, but you should check that your DNS is working, and what mti2935 said is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to connect to smtp.alestraune.net.mx on port 587 from a few hosts that I tested from.  It's possible that your hosting company may be blocking outgoing connections on port 587.  Some hosting companies are notorious for doing this, as they want to control outgoing mail from their hosting servers.